# Is it possible to disable (freeze) a package?

Tags: package-management

I am eager to know if it is possible to keep some packages disabled in Ubuntu, similar to how we can freeze / disable an app in Android.

i.e. The package is installed but not usable until it is reactivated.

N.B. I am not asking about just "disable update", I ask about "disable package".

If it's possible, then how can we do that?

Comment: What effect would you expect from this?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Personally, if I want to deactivate a package I uninstall it and if I want to reactivate it I simply install it again. Have you considered this extremely simple approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linux doesn't start applications you don't need and keep them in RAM like Android does so they can receive push messages and the like. So freezing packages is not necessary.

For many applications, if you don't start the application, it won't run. It will still get updates in case you want to use it.

If you are really inclined to get rid of a package, uninstalling it (and installing it as needed) is possible for non-essential applications, but as with other Linux distributions, packages on Ubuntu depend on other packages, and have other packages that depend on them, so when you install or remove a package, other packages may be automatically installed as dependencies (or replacements) or removed because they depend on the package you remove. Removing a package with many dependencies or that is essential for the system to run properly may break the system very severely. All this is handled by the package management system. To see what is going to happen when you run a particular install or remove command, use the `-s` or `--simulate` option in APT, for example

```
apt remove <package> -s
```

this will show what will be done without actually doing anything.

Some programs do run in the background as services though. In those cases, you can use the `systemctl` command (part of the interface of `systemd` to stop and disable them (disabling prevents the service from starting on boot). Once again, you need to be careful here, because services may also depend on each other and stopping or disabling an important service can have a negative impact on your system's functionality and stability. However, `systemd` will start services you have disabled if other services depend on them, so this is less breakable than package management.

Here are examples on how to stop, enable, disable and start services.

1. enabling a service:

   Enabling a service does not start it automatically; you need to use `start` for that, or add the `--now` flag, or reboot your machine. to make it take effect.

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable <service-name>
   ```
2. disabling a service:

   Disabling a service does not make it stop immediately, you need to use `stop` for that, or add the `--now` flag, or reboot your machine.

   ```
   sudo systemctl disable <service-name>
   ```
3. starting a service:

   starting a service does not make it enabled by default (this is what the `enable` command is for) but it starts the service immediately if it can be started.

   ```
   sudo systemctl start <service-name>
   ```
4. stopping a service:

   stopping a service does not disable a service which was enabled but stops it for the time being until next reboot.

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop <service-name>
   ```
5. restarting a service:

   Restarts a service but like the `start` and `stop` commands does not affect whether the service will be loaded and started on boot (the behaviour controlled by the `enable` `disable` commands.

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart <service-name>
   ```

Comment: I disagree. Some package installs services which starts at boottime. So, freezing makes sense for some of them. For example, a database application

Comment: Then disabling the service would be the right approach or uninstalling, but i guess when you use a database application which in fact needs a database, you might not want to freeze the database process/service.

Comment: Yes, but this is just an example. Some applications install services, desktop menu, menu entries, ui modifications etc.

Answer (score 2):

Linux, unlike the Android, which has something resembling a jail between different packages, uses shared libraries between packages.  If you were able to disable a package, it would be unclear which components you are removing the functionality from.

As many have already mentioned, you have the option to uninstalled the packages you don't want, for the interim you don't want it enabled.  This way the package and all the libraries used exclusively by it will be removed.  The libraries that are used by other packages will not be removed.

**Many Packages use services**

There is a facility to enable or disable services or to set the services to only run if you actively start it.  Packages that use services, under normal circumstances, will have the service started after the package is installed and will be enabled on startup by default.

An example of this is the **Apache2** package.  When it's installed the service is started and set to start automatically each time you reboot the computer.

**Use systemctl to start, stop, enable, disable services**

You can check your list of services to see if the package you want temporarily disabled by listing the installed services filtered by your specific package name.  In this example, I'll look for Apache2.

(This is the command and output to check the installation and status of Apache2.  It's filtering a list of all installed packages for `apache2`.)

```
$ systemctl | egrep apache2
apache2.service                    loaded active running   LSB: Apache2 web server
```

**The service can be status checked, started, stopped or disabled with these commands:**

Replace the option with one of these: `status` `start`, `stop`, `restart`, `disable`, `enable`.

(Command and output of status of a service)

```
$ sudo systemctrl status apache2
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-10-31 12:14:42 EDT; 2 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 17861 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1864 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─ 2119 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17909 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─21395 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─21397 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─21398 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─21399 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─21400 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─21401 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─21402 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─21403 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─31543 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Oct 31 12:14:42 ubunzeus apache2[1864]:  *
Oct 31 12:14:42 ubunzeus systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 01 07:35:02 ubunzeus systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 01 07:35:02 ubunzeus apache2[759]:  * Reloading Apache httpd web server apache2
Nov 01 07:35:02 ubunzeus apache2[759]:  *
Nov 01 07:35:02 ubunzeus systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 02 07:35:03 ubunzeus systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 02 07:35:03 ubunzeus apache2[17861]:  * Reloading Apache httpd web server apache2
Nov 02 07:35:04 ubunzeus apache2[17861]:  *
Nov 02 07:35:04 ubunzeus systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

You can do the same with any of the more than a hundred services that are installed and enabled on a default Ubuntu installation.  Or, is installed and enabled when you install a package, such as, `Apache2`, `Openssh-server`, `Mysql`, `Plexmedia Server`, and so on.

You can disable `ssh` without uninstalling `openssh-server` by running:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable sshd
```

The `ssh` login will be disabled(frozen) until you reenable it using the `enable` option of `systemctl`.

You may have to review the documentation of the package you install to see which service or services it start for using the package.

**Quick answer**

You can disable (freeze) packages by disabling the package's services.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a regular application you can remove the executable rights to it, thus making it "unusable". You can do that like so (I'm using `/usr/bin/gedit` as the example here):

```
$ sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/gedit
```

If you need to use it again:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/gedit
```

For systemd units, see the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

No, currently Ubuntu doesn't have this feature. If you're not using a package but may use it in future, you need to uninstall it and install later when you're ready to use it.